# Using .FromSql to run Stored Precedure in EntityFrameworkCore 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I need to run a stored procedure on my MSSQL Db through EntityFrameworkCore 2. I have the following method;

```
 public IList<Trader> GetTradersWithinRadius(int category, decimal latitude, decimal longitude)
        {
            var sproc = "FindTradersWithinRadius";
            var sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>()
            {
                new SqlParameter("@CATEGORY", category),
                new SqlParameter("@LATITUDE", latitude),
                new SqlParameter("@LONGITUDE", longitude),
            };
            var parameters = sqlParams.ToArray<object>();

            return this.Traders.FromSql($"{sproc} @CATEGORY, @LATITUDE, @LONGITUDE", sqlParams).ToList();
        }
```

However EF is giving the following error when running?

> No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type `List<SqlParameter>`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here please?

Comment: `params object[]` trap. Use `parameters` array instead of `sqlParams` list.

Comment: couldnt see the wood for the trees, thanks @IvanStoev if you want to leave the answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 4):

`List<SqlParameter>()` will not work for passing parameter to `StoredProcedure`. You better use `SqlParameter[]` (array of `SqlParameter`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code instead of using `FromSql` if you have DBContext in the scope

```
_databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"EXEC {storedProcedureName} @param1, @param2", new SqlParameter("param1", param1), new SqlParameter("param2", param2));
```